# Developing mobile front-end after browser version complete

Tags: angularjs, mobile, frontend, backend

Assuming I have already built out my application's server-side backend in PHP 7/ Laravel and browser front end in Angular JS... what frameworks should I use when I then want to start developing iOS and Android **native** apps?

How can I avoid redundant code (DRY) on different frameworks when hooking new mobile apps into my already existing backend?

Most of the information that I find on this subject mentions implementing WebViews (HTML5/JS) in the native app. I also found Apache Cordova for "cross-platform development." https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Ionic Framework for the past year and it has been pretty decent
http://ionicframework.com/

Comment: Thank you. That is most of what I have been finding. Ionic + Apache Cordova.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/

Comment: They have also lot good stuff for helping your development like,  Ionic Deploy http://docs.ionic.io/docs/deploy-from-scratch and Ionic Push https://apps.ionic.io/landing/push

Comment: Still havent tried out the Ionic Deploy but it seems legit :)